# Изменение значения внутри строки

Tags: c#, строки

Есть ли способ изменить значение внутри строки не переводя её в массив символов? Например "Машинная сила" в "Машинная пила".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Нет.**

Строки в C# неизменяемые, так что вам придётся создавать новую строку, изменить уже существующую строку невозможно*.

Если нужна запись символов по индексу, то проще всего перегнать строку в `StringBuilder`, в котором можно менять значения по индексу, а также добавлять их и удалять. А после окончания обработки снова перегнать в строку:

```
string s = "Машинная сила";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb[9] = 'п';
s = sb.ToString();
```

Если нужно заменить один символ, может быть проще всего откусить подстроку до этого символа и после, и сконкатенировать.

Обратите внимание, что в коде у меня каждый раз создаётся *новая* строка, так что те, кто имел ссылку на старую строку, не увидят изменений.

---

*Ну то есть возможно через unsafe-код или там рефлексию, но если вы так сделаете, ваш тимлид и вся команда прибегут бить вас после первого же code review.

Comment: Вариант с Substring имхо зря показал, копипастеры растащат, а вариант то по сути вредный ибо генерирует мусор в памяти.

Comment: @rdorn: И то правда. Уберу-ка его от греха подальше.

Comment: @rdorn, не согласен. Вариант со StringBuilder по памяти в данном случае такой же. VladD, верни обратно)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Идея в том, что его будут использовать в цикле или ещё чём-то таком. Вариант со `StringBuilder`'ом мне нравится больше. Ну и тут у нас один выброшенный промежуточный объект (сам `StringBuilder`), а с суммой получается три: две подстроки и промежуточная сумма (хотя это может быть и соптимизируется в два).

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну и по идее код можно восстановить, подсмотрев в историю или просто по словесному описанию.

Comment: @VladD, компилятор из сложения строк должен бы сам собрать вызов String.Concat. Получается 2 выброшенные подстроки, в сумме на ту же длину, что StringBuilder. К тому же, быстрее было бы через массив char'ов.

Comment: @Qwertiy массив чаров ТС сам уже предложил. А насчёт быстрее: вряд ли, скорее одинаково, StringBuilder  внутри и есть массив чартов, только интерфейс побогаче, но это на скорость не влияет

Comment: @VladD а как же верные последователи C++ в C#, которые кричат во весь голос что - "unsafe код уменьшает время, увеличивает производительность и оптимизирует код". Кстати в легасикоде, старых проектов, на гите или внутри конторы где работаю, и там где до этого работал, не видел ни одной unsafe реализации.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: А вот этих последователей адекватный тимлид гонит из команды вон в момент. Если кто хочет писать на C++ — вот и пусть пишет на C++ со всеми его недостатками, а не превращает C# в C++.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: А если тимлид сам такой, то лучше от него сразу бежать. Наверняка он ещё не разрешает LINQ и исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `unsafe`-код, если нужно менять строку. Редко когда такое действительно оправдано, но возможно вам нужно чтобы ваш код очень быстро работал.

В общем это можно делать на свой страх и риск, когда вы уверены, что вы всё предусмотрели и вам нужна действительно огромная производительность.

```
string s = "Машинная сила";

unsafe
{
    fixed (char* chars = s)
    {
        chars[9] = 'п';
    }
}
```

Чтобы это компилировалось в свойствах проекта следует отметить галочку `Allow unsafe code`.

#### Побочные эффекты

Однако из-за интернирования строк в C# также строки с тем же значением поменяются (спасибо @VladD за эту мысль):

```
public static void Main()
{
    A();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world"); // Выведет "Hello bugs!"
}

public static unsafe void A()
{
    string s = string.Intern("Hello world");
    fixed (char* p = s)
    {
        p[6] = 'b'; p[7] = 'u'; p[8] = 'g'; p[9] = 's'; p[10] = '!';
    }
}
```

Без `string.Intern` данное поведение также сохраняется.

Comment: Зря вы новичку посоветовали unsafe-код. Теперь он везде будет «для производительности» использовать такое.

Comment: Да кто знает кто увидит этот код. Вдруг кто-то пишет высокопроизводительные программы. Тем более я вроде бы добавил чёткое предостережение. Если недостаточно убедительно отговариваю — можете отредактировать, добавить более убедительных предостережений, привести веские аргументы.

Comment: Мне кажется, если кто-то пишет высокопроизводительные программы, он вовсе не пользуется типом `string`. :-\

Comment: И он вообще решит, что скорей на C/C++ надо.:)

Comment: А проблема подхода заключается например вот в этом: http://ideone.com/ThHtmu

Comment: @VladD Ух-ты, прикольная мысль про интернирование строк. Как-нибудь в ответ добавлю. Сейчас уже спать пойду.

Comment: А, и правда, строковые константы же интернируются сами по себе.